# Browsing WPD's content through Windows Explorer

Tags: c++, shell, wpd

I noticed that when I plug in my Nokia phone, an icon will appear in My Computer in windows explorer and I can browse the content of my phone through windows explorer.

Is this concept similar to developing Shell Namespace Extension for virtual folder? I notice that Shell Namespace Extension is categorised as System Folder while my phone is categorized as Mobile Phone.

Virtual folder NSE's icon will remain in my computer while my phone's icon will disappear when I unplug my phone. Is it possible to achieve the same for a virtual folder NSE so that it will hide itself in respond to a device being plugged out and will reappear when the device is plugged in? I am thinking of developing a virtual folder NSE that display the content of phone differently.

The scenario will be like this: When I plug my phone, two icon will appear on my computer, one that is default nokia icon and another that is my NSE icon. My NSE icon will only display image file, for example. Unplugging my phone will make these two icons disappear from my computer.

Last question, do WPD driver developer need to implement their own Shell Namespace Extension handler so that content of WPD device can be browsed through Explorer? or do they only need to implement the WPD driver for the device and the explorer will be able to browse them?

Answer (score 0):

For the last part of your question

The WPD Driver only needs to implement WPD and explorer will take care of showing it in my computer and so on